# starting celery worker from python script results in error - "click.exceptions.UsageError: No such command" using celery==5.1.2

Tags: python-3.x, celery

Directory structure:

[image]

Here is my **cw_manage_integration/psa_integration/api_service/sync_config/**init**.py**:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue

from psa_integration.celery_config import QUEUE, USER, MAX_PRIORITIES_SUPPORT_AT_TIME

BROKER = "amqp://{0}:{1}@{2}/xyz".format("abc", "pqrst", "x.x.x.x)
APP = Celery(
"sync service",
broker=BROKER,
backend='rpc://',
include=["psa_integration.sync_service.alert_sync.alert",
"psa_integration.sync_service.tenant_sync.tenant",
"psa_integration.sync_service.alert_sync.update_status"]
)
APP.conf.task_queues = [
Queue(QUEUE, queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': MAX_PRIORITIES_SUPPORT_AT_TIME}),
]
```

The below is the **cw_manage_integration/start_service.py**:

```
"""Scrip to start Sync service via Celery."""
from psa_integration.utils.logger import *
from psa_integration import sync_service
from psa_integration.celery_config import CELERY_CONCURRENCY

APP = sync_service.APP

try:
    APP.start(["__init__.py", "worker", "-c", str(CELERY_CONCURRENCY)])
except Exception as scheduler_exception:
    logging.exception("Exception occurred while starting services. Exception = {}".format(scheduler_exception))
```

When I run the command `python3 start_service.py` using celery version celery==4.4.5, it just works fine by starting celery workers.

But when the same start_service.py is run using  celery==5.1.2, it is throwing the below error:

```
>python3 start_service.py
```

> MainProcess INFO    2021-07-07 16:27:42,725 all_logs     
> 79  : started MainProcess INFO    2021-07-07 16:27:42,725 all_logs
>                              80  : log file name:
> /home/sdodmane/PycharmProjects/cw_manage_integration1/cw_manage_integration/psa_integration/logs/worker_2021-07-07.log
> MainProcess INFO    2021-07-07 16:27:42,725 all_logs     
> 81  : Level: 4 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/sdodmane/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click_didyoumean/**init**.py",
> line 34, in resolve_command
> return super(DYMMixin, self).resolve_command(ctx, args)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1188, in
> resolve_command
> ctx.fail('No such command "%s".' % original_cmd_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 496, in fail
> raise UsageError(message, self) click.exceptions.UsageError: No such command "**init**.py".
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "start_service.py", line 10,
> in 
> APP.start(["**init**.py", "worker", "-c", str(CELERY_CONCURRENCY)])   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 371,
> in start
> celery.main(args=argv, standalone_mode=False)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1132, in invoke
> cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)   File "/home/sdodmane/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click_didyoumean/**init**.py",
> line 42, in resolve_command
> raise click.exceptions.UsageError(error_msg, error.ctx) click.exceptions.UsageError: No such command "**init**.py".

Not able to differentiate between celery==4.4.5 and celery==5.1.2 in this context.
Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `start` method is broken in the current(5.1.2) release.
It has been fixed (https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/6825/files) but has not been released yet. Hopefully, the next release `v5.1.3` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix with the following change:

```
# celery==5.1.1
APP.start()

# celery==5.2.6
import sys
APP.start(argv=sys.argv[1:])
```

For you, that may mean removing the `__init__.py` in your list of args:

```
APP.start(["worker", "-c", str(CELERY_CONCURRENCY)])
```